# stuck in moving to sub directory

Tags: visual-studio

I got this error while going from parent directory to sub directory

`Set-Location : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Path'. Specified method is not 
supported.
At line:1 char:4
+ cd listing11,12,13
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Location], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand`
[image]
what this says ? how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS Code default setting doesn't allow using certain special characters in folder name while changing directories try using **-** instead of **,** in folder name or else change default setting, you can go trough official documentation of vs code [here](https://vscode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getstarted/settings/)